How to simulate a BJT in ngspice?
I am trying to simulate the STN0214 BJT (at least I believe it is a BJT) in ngspice. I have downloaded the PSPICE file from the manufacturer's website and am including it in the ngspice source as shown below (I have set ngbehavior=ps in my .spiceinit).
.title mine
.include STN0214.lib
R1 pwr res 1000ohm
Q1 res gat 0 STN0214
V1 pwr 0 5
V2 gat 0 dc 0 PULSE (0 6 0.1m 0.01m 0.01m 0.1m 0.2m)
.options savecurrents
.tran 0.0001m 10m
.control
run
plot pwr-0 gat-0 @R1[i]
.endc
.end

Unfortunately the schematic editor tool on this site does not work in the Chromium browser so I cannot easily include a proper graphical schematic, but here is an ASCII art one:
# pwr
#  |
#  R1
#  |
# res
#  |
#  Q1--gat
#  |
#  0

I get the following error, and a graph that is truncated on the horizontal axis.
doAnalyses: TRAN:  Timestep too small; time = 0.000100001, timestep = 1.25e-19: trouble with stn0214-instance q1

What I would like to see is current across R1 that is generally higher when the gate is being driven by the pulse voltage than when it isn't.
I suspect the simulation is running into infinite or negative currents but I have little understanding as to why. There is probably something wrong with the circuit; any advice appreciated.
At the suggestion of Sphero in the comments, I've added a resistor on the base/gate of the BJT. There was no improvement and the same error message resulted (I tried a wide variety of values for R2). Here is the revised file:
.title mine
.include STN0214.lib
R1 pwr res 1000ohm
R2 gat reg 10000ohm
Q1 res reg 0 STN0214
V1 pwr 0 5
V2 gat 0 dc 0 PULSE (0 6 0.1m 0.01m 0.01m 0.1m 0.2m)
.options savecurrents
.tran 0.0001m 10m
.control
run
plot pwr-0 gat-0 @R1[i]
.endc
.end
# pwr
#  |
#  R1
#  |
# res
#  |
#  Q1--reg--R2--gat
#  |
#  0


I don't know if this is your problem, but you do need a series resistor on the base or the base current will be (fatally) excessive at 6V Vbe.

It would help to know the contents of STN0214.lib.

@SpehroPefhany Thanks, that turned out not to be the root cause but is probably sound advice and I have incorporated such a resistor in my file.

@Hearth It can be downloded here: https://www.st.com/en/power-transistors/stn0214.html#cad-resources I don't want to post its contents due to an abundance of caution around copyright issues.

I think I'm getting somewhat better results now after changing the Q line to Q1 0 reg res STN0214 so that 0 and res are swapped versus how they were previously.

I duplicated your netlist in LTspice and it doesn't seem to have any issues.  I'm not sure why ngspice is having timestep errors with this...

There seems to be an issue with the BJT model.  If I use a different model, ngspice doesn't choke out.  This might be a question better suited for a support ticket on the ngspice sourceforge:  https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/support-requests/
